# Is it possible to use razor views in angular cli components template?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, angular-cli, angular-components

Presently, I can use only html template in angular cli component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

I am using angular CLI in ASP.NET core MVC application.  Can I use views from from MVC application as template to the angular template like below:

```
templateUrl: './Template/Index',
```

Currently it seems it doesn't work as the time of building angular app it is not able to resolve the template.  Because it doesn't exist.

I am just exploring if it is possible.

Comment: You likely can build it with JIT and ` --no-aot` flag. You can't do that with AOT since these 2 things are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I faced the same issue. I ended up using the index.html page instead and replacing the razor view with a Web API endpoint. Then I fetched the data when initializing the app. See my answer here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027957/64279