# Custom filter not working in Angular Hybrid app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, angular5, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am attempting to convert an AngularJS 1.6 app in to a hybrid app along with Angular 5. I have the following simple filter defined:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var filterId = "colorPicker";

    angular
        .module('app')
        .filter('colorPicker', colorPicker);

    function colorPicker() {
        return function (input) {
            var colorCode = '#2980b9';
            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    colorCode = '#16a085';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    colorCode = '#a38761';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    colorCode = '#8e44ad';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    colorCode = '#ffa800';
                    break;
                case 5:
                    colorCode = '#d95459';
                    break;
                case 6:
                    colorCode = '#8eb021';
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return colorCode;
        };
    }
})();
```

The filter is used like this: `ng-attr-style="background-color: {{ $index | colorPicker }}"`

This works in the AngularJS app, but I get the following error in the Hybrid app: `angular.js:14525 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: colorPickerFilterProvider <- colorPickerFilter`

The filter is called from the AngularJS code as it has before. In fact, I barely have any Angular 5 code. I'm just trying to get the existing code to run as it has been, but within the Hybrid app. Shouldn't I be able to use filters as before?

**Update**

I think this might be related to other errors I'm getting about controllers:

`[$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'myController' is not registered.`

I can see the script files downloading successfully and no errors are being thrown when my `app.module.ts` bootstraps AngularJS. In fact, I'm somewhat certain that AngularJS is running since it was getting an error about `globalVars` not being injected (this was being defined in a razor view that I am no longer using) but the error went away after I recreated it in TypeScript and "downgraded" it so AngularJS could use it.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { downgradeInjectable, UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GlobalVarsService } from './core/global-vars.service';

declare var angular: any;

angular.module('app', []).factory('globalVars', downgradeInjectable(GlobalVarsService));

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  providers: [
    GlobalVarsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], { strictDi: true });
  }
}
```

So the files are downloading and executing, but the controllers and filter (and maybe other items) are not found by the app. I put all the old code in a folder named "old" and then updated `.angular-cli.json` to copy these files to the output upon build so that I can reference them via `<script>` tags in the index.html. This should work, shouldn't it? Or do the files need to be bundled with the Angular 5 files for some reason?

```
// .angular-cli.json section
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../old/app/", "output": "./app/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../old/Content/", "output": "./Content/" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../old/Scripts/", "output": "./Scripts/" },
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Actually I think there were two problems. One was that I think I was *redefining* "app" by including square brackets when downgrading my `globalVars` service.

`angular.module('app', []).factory('globalVars', downgradeInjectable(GlobalVarsService));`

instead of

`angular.module('app').factory('globalVars', downgradeInjectable(GlobalVarsService));`

The other issue I think was a chicken-and-the-egg kind of problem. My `globalVars` was being injected into my AngularJS app's config function, but I think the app might have been needed to downgrade `globalVars` - still not completely sure. Luckily for me, nothing was referencing `globalVars` in my `app.js` so I was able to remove the reference.

This is the version of my `app.module.ts` that finally got it working. I hope this helps someone else!

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { downgradeInjectable, UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GlobalVarsService } from './core/global-vars.service';

declare var angular: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: OnAppInit,
      multi: true,
      deps: [GlobalVarsService, HttpClient]
    },
    GlobalVarsService
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule, private http: HttpClient) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    angular.module('app').factory('globalVars', downgradeInjectable(GlobalVarsService));
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'], { strictDi: true });
  }
}

export function OnAppInit(globalVars: GlobalVarsService, http: HttpClient) {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Fetch data from the server before initializing the app.
      http.get(environment.apiBase + '/api/meta/data').subscribe(x => {
        globalVars.MetaData = x;
        globalVars.VersionNumber = globalVars.MetaData.versionNumber;
        globalVars.IsDebugBuild = globalVars.MetaData.isDebugBuild;
        globalVars.AuthorizedFeatures = globalVars.MetaData.authorizedFeatures;
        globalVars.User = globalVars.MetaData.user;
        resolve();
      });
    });
  };
}
```